# Internal error when using MPI Intel library with reduction operation on communicators

Tags: c++, mpi, numa

I am having some issues when using reduction operations on MPI communicators.

I have a lots of different communicators created using the algorithm this way :

```
MPI_ERR_SONDAGE(MPI_Group_incl(world_group, comm_size, &(on_going_communicator[0]), &local_group));
MPI_ERR_SONDAGE(MPI_Comm_create_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, local_group, tag, &communicator)); tag++;
```

When I call a reduction operation like so :

```
MPI_ERR_SONDAGE(MPI_Allreduce(&(temporary[0]), &(temporary_glo[0]), (int)lignes.size(), MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MAX, communicator));
```

I get

> Assertion failed in file ../../src/mpid/ch4/src/intel/ch4_shm_coll.c
> at line 2266: comm->shm_numa_layout[my_numa_node].base_addr
> /.../oneapi/2021.4.0/mpi/2021.4.0/lib/release/libmpi.so.12(MPL_backtrace_show+0x1c) [0x2ace34033c8c]
> /Cci/Admin/oneapi/2021.4.0/mpi/2021.4.0/lib/release/libmpi.so.12(MPIR_Assert_fail+0x21)
> [0x2ace33aaffe1]
> /.../oneapi/2021.4.0/mpi/2021.4.0/lib/release/libmpi.so.12(+0x24f609)
> [0x2ace337c6609]
> /.../oneapi/2021.4.0/mpi/2021.4.0/lib/release/libmpi.so.12(+0x19b518)
> [0x2ace33712518]
> /.../oneapi/2021.4.0/mpi/2021.4.0/lib/release/libmpi.so.12(+0x1686aa)
> [0x2ace336df6aa]
> /.../oneapi/2021.4.0/mpi/2021.4.0/lib/release/libmpi.so.12(+0x251ac7)
> [0x2ace337c8ac7]
> /Cci/Admin/oneapi/2021.4.0/mpi/2021.4.0/lib/release/libmpi.so.12(PMPI_Allreduce+0x562)
> [0x2ace33685712]

I only have this problem on big test cases. Meaning lots of communicators with a reasonnable amount of data to reduce. So I cannot create a MCVE, sorry.

When I set the environment variables I_MPI_COLL_DIRECT=off and I_MPI_COLL_INTRANODE=pt2pt, the code works fine. Since I guess the problem is induced by the use of NUMA and I guess forcing point to point communication will inhibit the use of NUMA.

But my fear is that these options will lead to degraded performance, so I really would like to know the bottom problem.

I have tried with :
intel/2020.1.217
intel/2020.2.254
intel/2021.4.0

And they basically show the same error.

Could you tell me or give me a hint of what is going on ?

Thank you.

Comment: Later is the code the product of the call Comm_create_group is used like  MPI_ERR_SONDAGE(MPI_Comm_dup(communicator, &(sond->communicator)));
Have you even read the fact that the code works when I set the environment variable  I_MPI_COLL_INTRANODE=pt2pt, it wouldn't work if the error was so obvious. And what is that remark concerning local variables ?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code because of all the horizontal scrolling that's needed. Ceterum sensio you should use local variables.

Comment: Judging from [this](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-HPC-Toolkit/MPI-program-aborts-with-an-quot-Assertion-failed-in-file-ch4-shm/td-p/1370537) post, it might very well be a bug in the MPI library rather than a user mistake.